# Is posible create square with text inside and others figure with jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, typescript, pdf, jspdf

[image: PDF craeted with puppeteer]

I created a PDF but with package puppeteer getting to url "https://example.com/pdf/export" but I desire create with jsPDF from zero with jsPDF because the time of download and steps are less, however I need create special figures for example transparent square and others, but In my research I couldn't find something for create a square with dynamical widths(See the img for understanme)

or is possible create PDF from url with jsPDF?